# take print from webview using javafx

Tags: java, printing, webview, javafx-2

I am trying to open HTML file in web view using JavaFX. Now I want to print `WebView` content.

Here is my code:

```
Group group= new Group();
Scene scene= new Scene(group);
fxpanel.setScene(scene);  
WebEngine eng;
WebView webview = new WebView ();
group.getChildren().add(webview);
webview.setMinSize(740,430);
webview.setMaxSize(740,430);  
webview.setVisible(true);
eng= webview.getEngine();


try
{ 
    eng.load(new File("path of the htmlfile").toURI().toURL().toString());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"exception") ;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing WebView will be added as a feature for Java 8.

You can download a [Java 8 pre-release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) which will implement the feature.

Java 8 is due for release in March of next year.

---

Feature Tracker: [RT-17666 Webview and HTMLEditor should support printing their content](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8101135)

---

*Side Note*: 
In your posted code you mix JavaFX and Swing code on the same thread.  Normally, you should not do that => see the [JavaFX Swing Interoperability Tutorial for details](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the JavaFX 8 PrintJob and Printer APIs to print any JavaFX scene graph node.

Here's the link to the post:
http://carlfx.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/introduction-by-example-javafx-8-printing/

The magic lies in this function: it takes your webview and prints out to the default printer

```
public void print(final Node node) {
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
    double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
    double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
    node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(node);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```