# print a html file using java or javafx

Tags: java, printing, javafx

I am creating a html file using java program . HTML file is using `CSS` also . I am opening this file using javafx webview. Is it possible to send this html file to print command using java 
I am doing this by opening the file in `JEditorPane` and then print the `jeditorpane`.

For Printing through `JEditorPane` ,I am using the following code.

```
 try

  {

    File HtmlFile= new File("path of file");
    JEditorPane htmlPane= new JEditorPane();
    htmlPane.setPage(htmlFile.toString());
    htmlPane.print();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: You have the code, what is the problem?

Comment: it does not support html files with CSS

Comment: possible duplicate of [take print from webview using javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271820/take-print-from-webview-using-javafx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JEditorPane` does not support the full `CSS` specification.

The only advice I can offer is to look at alternative HTML/CSS renders for Java. One that I can recommend is the [xhtmlrenderer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) project. Development has slowed down of late, but nevertheless, it can serve your purpose